# Left floating equal height

Tags: html, css

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div style="float: left; width: 300px; border: 1px solid black;">
                testomgsgo<br/>
                testete<br/>
                testete<br/>
                testete<br/>
                testete<br/>
            </div>
            <div style="float: left; width: 300px; border: 1px solid black;">
                <div style="background: #FF0000; width: 50px; height: 50px; margin-left: auto;"></div>
            </div>
            <div style="clear: both"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

With the above code the left hand side will have variable content and I need the div in the right hand div (the red box) to site at the bottom so its bottom edge is flush with the bottom of the left div height.

I've tried using auto top margin but I believe the problem is that I can't get the height of the right side div to match the left side div.

Is there some way with CSS to do this or do I have to resort to javascript to match the heights?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/7b3Pc/

Basically, the variable div controls the height of all other sibling divs through its parent div.  Siblings absolutely positioned and height:100%.

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div style=" width:600px; border: 1px solid black; position:relative">
                <div style="width: 300px;">
                testomgsgo<br/>
                testete<br/>
                testete<br/>
                testete<br/>
                testete<br/>
            </div>
                <div style="width: 300px; height:100%; position:absolute; top:0;left:300px; border: 1px solid black;">
                    <div style="background: #FF0000; width: 50px; height:100%; margin-left: auto;">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's just conjecture, but only one of us didn't get down voted. +1 to level the playing field.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/htfRw/

Tested in Safari, Firefox

**EDIT:**

Here it is inside a container: http://jsfiddle.net/htfRw/2/

Comment: This works if he wants 100% height (as in height of the page). I think he wants the columns in a container.

Comment: Yeah exactly, this is really close though

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
margin-top: 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need to use `float` here at all. I'd recommend using `display: inline-block` instead, because you can then rely on the `vertical-align` property to vertically position your second `<div>` instead of using `margin` .

HTML:

```
<div>
    testomgsgo<br/>
    testete<br/>
    testete<br/>
    testete<br/>
    testete<br/>
</div><div class="second">
    <div></div>
</div>
```

*Note that there is no space between the closing `</div>` and `<div class="second">`. Because both of these elements are inline elements, any whitespace in the markup will cause there to be small, horizontal space between the two elements.*

CSS:

```
body > div {
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    display: inline-block; }
.second div {
    background: #FF0000; 
    width: 50px; 
    height: 50px; }
```

Preview: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/FwD3Q/